# Pandas - Count the number of rows that would be true for a function - for each input row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that needs a column added to it. That column needs to be a count of all the other rows in the table that meet a certain condition, that condition needs to take in input both from the "input" row and the "output" row.

For example, if it was a dataframe describing people, and I wanted to make a column that counted how many people were taller than the current row and lighter.

I'd want the height and weight of the row, as well as the height and weight of the other rows in a function, so I can do something like:

```
def example_function(height1, weight1, height2, weight2):
    if height1 > height2 and weight1 < weight2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And it would just sum up all the True's and give that sum in the column.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Edit: Sample input:

```
id   name    height   weight   country
0    Adam    70       180      USA
1    Bill    65       190      CANADA
2    Chris   71       150      GERMANY
3    Eric    72       210      USA
4    Fred    74       160      FRANCE
5    Gary    75       220      MEXICO
6    Henry   61       230      SPAIN
```

The result would need to be:

```
id   name    height   weight   country   new_column
0    Adam    70       180      USA       1
1    Bill    65       190      CANADA    1
2    Chris   71       150      GERMANY   3
3    Eric    72       210      USA       1
4    Fred    74       160      FRANCE    4
5    Gary    75       220      MEXICO    1
6    Henry   61       230      SPAIN     0
```

I believe it will need to be some sort of function, as the actual logic I need to use is more complicated.

edit 2:fixed typo

Comment: Post a sample and desired output of what you are tying to achieve.

Comment: Do you need `mask = (df.height1 > df.weight1) & (df.weight1 < df.weight2)` ?

Comment: Let me add the sample @shivsn requested. Editing...

Comment: @firestreak - Can you explain new column? What is logic?

Comment: It's the number of rows that meet the condtions compare to the current row. For example there's 4 people that are both shorter and heavier than Fred. There are no people that are shorter and heavier than Henry.

Comment: @firestreak - I change my solution what is same principe as lambda function of Ami Tavory solution, it seems first value in output is `2`, not `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add booleans, like this:

```
count = ((df.height1 > df.height2) & (df.weight1 < df.weight2)).sum()
```

EDIT:

I test it a bit and then change conditions with custom function:

```
def f(x):
    #check boolean mask 
    #print ((df.height > x.height) & (df.weight < x.weight))
    return ((df.height < x.height) & (df.weight > x.weight)).sum()

df['new_column'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
   id   name  height  weight  country  new_column
0   0   Adam      70     180      USA           2
1   1   Bill      65     190   CANADA           1
2   2  Chris      71     150  GERMANY           3
3   3   Eric      72     210      USA           1
4   4   Fred      74     160   FRANCE           4
5   5   Gary      75     220   MEXICO           1
6   6  Henry      61     230    SPAIN           0
```

**Explanation**:

For each row compare values and for count simply `sum` values `True`.

Comment: @Jonas Byström - Thank you. Also waiting for data sample of OP, then solution should be explain more :)

Comment: I think you copied a typo from the OP's code - there was no intention to compare height to weight, IIUC.

Comment: @firestreak - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if it was a dataframe describing people, and I wanted to make a column that counted how many people were taller than the current row and lighter.

As far as I understand, you want to assign to a new column something like

```
df['num_heigher_and_leighter'] = df.apply(lambda r: ((df.height > r.height) & (df.weight < r.weight)).sum(), axis=1)
```

However, your text description doesn't seem to match the outcome, which is:

```
0    2
1    3
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    6
dtype: int64
```

**Edit**

As in any other case, you can use a named function instead of a lambda:

```
df = ...

def foo(r):
    return ((df.height > r.height) & (df.weight < r.weight)).sum()

df['num_heigher_and_leighter'] = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to spin this lambda off into a separately called function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you had a typo and want to compare *heights with heights* and *weights with weights*. If so, you could count the number of persons taller *OR* heavier like so:

```
>>> for i,height,weight in zip(df.index,df.height, df.weight):
...     cnt = df.loc[((df.height>height) & (df.weight>weight)), 'height'].count()
...     df.loc[i,'thing'] = cnt
...
>>> df
    name  height  weight  country  thing
0   Adam      70     180      USA    2.0
1   Bill      65     190   CANADA    2.0
2  Chris      71     150  GERMANY    3.0
3   Eric      72     210      USA    1.0
4   Fred      74     160   FRANCE    1.0
5   Gary      75     220   MEXICO    0.0
6  Henry      61     230    SPAIN    0.0
```

Here for instance, no person is Heavier than Henry, and no person is taller than Gary. If that's not what you intended, it should be easy to modify the `&` above to a `|` instead or switching out the `>` to a `<`.

When you're more accustomed to Pandas, I suggest you use [Ami Tavory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3510736/ami-tavory) excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49727011/87973) instead.

PS. For the love of god, use the Metric system for representing weight and height, and convert to whatever for presentation. These numbers are totally nonsensical for the world population at large. :)

Comment: Is it possible to spin off the ((df.height>height) & (df.weight>weight)) into a separately called function, where df.height, df.weight, height and weight will be arguments, and I return True or False?

Comment: By the way, not really uses imperial system - this is all an abstraction so I can ask the question with an easier to understand example.